# Solidity ParserError: Expected identifier but got '='

Tags: constructor, ethereum, identifier, solidity, parsing-error

Why does the code below contain an error (`ParserError: Expected identifier but got '='`).

```
contract Test {

    struct Box {
        uint size;
    }

    Box public box;
    box.size = 3;    //<-- error here

    constructor() public {
    }

}
```

It works if I put the `box.size = 3;` into the `constructor`!

```
contract Test {

    struct Box {
        uint size;
    }

    Box public box;

    constructor() public {
        box.size = 3;
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't use Solidity, but I guess you can't have assignments outside a function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The grammar doesn't allow assignments on contract level. But it allows declarations of state variables and [these can contain an initializer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1511/how-to-initialize-a-struct). Therefore you can initialize it with

```
Box public box = Box({ size: 3 });
```

or

```
Box public box = Box(3);
```